# Ошибка NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object в unity3d

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-ui

Делал простенькую игру на юнити, где надо корзиной яблоки ловить, но почему-то возвращает null когда я хочу извлечь компонент Text из ScoreCounter

````
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Unity.VisualScripting;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.UIElements;

public class Basket : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("Set Dynamically")]
    public Text scoreGT;
    void Start()
    {
        GameObject scoreGO = GameObject.Find("ScoreCounter");
        scoreGT = scoreGO.gameObject.GetComponent<Text>();  # в этой строке возвращает null
        scoreGT.text = "0";
    }
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Vector3 mousePos2D = Input.mousePosition;
        mousePos2D.z = -Camera.main.transform.position.z;

        Vector3 mousePos3D = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(mousePos2D);
        Vector3 pos = this.transform.position;
        pos.x = mousePos3D.x;
        this.transform.position = pos;
    }
    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision coll)
    {
        GameObject collidewith = coll.gameObject;
        if(collidewith.tag == "Apple")
        {   
            collidewith.transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.green;
        }
        int score = int.Parse(scoreGT.text);
        score += 100;
        scoreGT.text = score.ToString();
    }
} ```
````